# Open source CMS with REST based api support

Tags: java, xml, content-management-system

Is there any open source CMS in a java/xml platform which supports REST based apis ?
Basically i like to deploy a CMS as well a widget like application  who can communicate each other via REST? Have tried openCms and couple of others too, but couldn't figure out a proper interface either via http or rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal allows you to do that using the Services project at http://drupal.org/project/services

It provides a REST based interface for CRUD access to its content and some other services.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Hippo CMS](http://www.onehippo.org); it's open source, Java based and offers a JCR based content repository with [REST capabilities](https://wiki.onehippo.com/display/CMS7/RESTful+JAX-RS+Component+Support+in+HST-2).

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it, however, https://getdirectus.com/ looks promising. I like the fact that it's built to be headless, meaning it's core function is to be a CMS with RESTful API, as opposed to the API being a secondary feature.